¿Cómo mostrar en una tabla, todos los registros similares a un DATO que tengo guardados en mi BD?
Mostrar en un tabla, todos los REGISTROS similares a un DATO guardados en mi BD.
¡Hola, a tod@s!
Estoy tratando de encontrar la instrucción para encontrar todos los REGISTROS similares que existan de un DATO en mi BD, y se desplieguen en una tabla.
Ej: Saber todos los registros con el número 22. Tengo más de 3 registros con ése número en mi BD. La idea, es que me aparezcan todos los registros cuándo los mande a llamar, y no sólo uno.
Me habían sugerido llegar a la solución con un sub-ciclo, pero, no encuentro el ¿cómo?.

El código que tengo, no me devuelve todos los registros que se relacionan con el "22". Las herramientas que estoy usando para el ejemplo, es servidor local XAMPP, HTML, PHP, MySQL y JavaScript.

CONEXION A MI BD (dbcontroller.php)
<?php
class DBController {
  private $host = "localhost";
  private $user = "root";
  private $password = "";
  private $database = "*";
  private $conexion;
  
  function __construct() {
    $this->conexion = $this->connectDB();
  }
  
  function connectDB() {
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
    return $conexion;
  }
  
  function runQuery($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conexion,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $resultset[] = $row;
    }
    if(!empty($resultset))
      return $resultset;
  }
  
  function insertQuery($query) {
      mysqli_query($this->conexion, $query);
      $insert_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->conexion);
      return $insert_id;
  }
  
  function getIds($query) {
      $result = mysqli_query($this->conexion,$query);
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          $resultset[] = $row[0];
      }
      if(!empty($resultset))
          return $resultset;
  }
  
   function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysqli_query($this->conexion, $query);
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;
    }
}
?>


Selección de datos a mi BD (dato1.php)
 <?php
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    # conectare la base de datos
 include('dbcontroller.php');
$db_handle = new DBController();

$return_arr = array();


$sqlc = "SELECT  * FROM base WHERE  CLAVE like '%".$_GET['term']."%'";

$faq = $db_handle->runQuery($sqlc);

foreach($faq as $k=>$v) {
/* Recuperar y almacenar en conjunto los resultados de la consulta.*/       
    $row_array['value'] = $faq[$k]['CLAVE'];
    $row_array['CLAVE']=$faq[$k]['CLAVE'];
    
    $row_array['DESCRIPCION']=$faq[$k]['DESCRIPCION'];
    $row_array['UM']=$faq[$k]['UM'];
    $row_array['ID']=$faq[$k]['ID'];
    $row_array['CLAVE']=$faq[$k]['CLAVE'];
    $row_array['LOTE']=$faq[$k]['LOTE'];
    $row_array['CADUCIDAD']=$faq[$k]['CADUCIDAD'];
    $row_array['EXISTENCIA']=$faq[$k]['EXISTENCIA'];
    
    
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
/* Codifica el resultado del array en JSON. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
?>

Intefaz (salidax3.php)
<?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '*');
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>GUI</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prueba.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.0.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<!--SCRIPT-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#CLAVE").autocomplete({
        source: "dato1.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#clave1').val(ui.item.clave1);
          $('#DESCRIPCION').val(ui.item.DESCRIPCION);
          $('#UM').val(ui.item.UM);
           $('#ID2').val(ui.item.ID2);
            $('#CLAVE2').val(ui.item.CLAVE2);
             $('#LOTE').val(ui.item.LOTE);
              $('#CADUCIDAD').val(ui.item.CADUCIDAD);
               $('#EXISTENCIA').val(ui.item.EXISTENCIA);


          $("#CLAVE").focus();
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
 
  <!-------------->
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  $(buscar_datos());
  function buscar_datos(consulta){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'dato1.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {consulta: consulta},
    })
    .done(function(respuesta){
      $("#datos").html(respuesta);
    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log("error");
      
    })
  } 
</script>
</head> 

<body>
  <h1 align="center"></h1>
  <div class="container">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">   
      <div class="card-group mt-3">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card text-center border-info">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">-</h4>
              </div>
            </div>   
          </div>

          <div class="col-9">
            <div class="card text-center border-info">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
                <br>
                <form action="entradados.php" method="POST" class="row g-3">
                 <!------->
                 <div class="row mb-3">
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">CLAVE</label>
                  <input type="text" name="CLAVE"class="form-control" id="CLAVE">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <label for="inputState" class="form-label">DESCRIPCION</label>
                  <input type="text" name="DESCRIPCION" class="form-control" id="DESCRIPCION">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <label for="inputZip" class="form-label">U.M.</label>
                  <input type="text" name="UM" class="form-control" id="UM">
                </div>
        <hr>
<!--TABLA-->
<div class="container">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">LOTE</th>
      <th scope="col">CADUCIDAD</th>
      <th scope="col">EXISTENCIA</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="text" value="" name="LOTE" id="LOTE"></th>
         <th><input type="text" name="CADUCIDAD" id="CADUCIDAD"></th>
          <th><input type="text" name="EXISTENCIA" id="EXISTENCIA"></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
</div>
<br>
<div class="">
</div>
<br>
</form>

</div>
</div>   
</div>
</div> 
</div>      
<br>
<!--SCRIPT-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>

<!------->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<!------->
</body>
</html

No pretendo que me den la solución, sólo les pido de favor que con su conocimiento y/o experiencia, me puedan guiar o dar sugerencias para trabajarlo y llegar al resultado.
Gracias

Supongo que debes cambiar esto: $row_array['value'] = $faq[$k]['CLAVE'];  por esto: $row_array['value'][] = $faq[$k]['CLAVE']; en todas las asignaciones de $row_away que estás haciendo, y a partir de alli podrás llevarte todas las coincidencias, pues ahora estas sobreescribiendo el mismo parámetro en cada iteración, y al terminar solo conservará la última, que debe ser la que estas viendo.

¡Hola, @masterguru!, gracias por tu respuesta. Ya intenté lo que me sugieres, y no me jala todos los registros cómo lo requiero. Seguiré buscando la solución, nuevamente, gracias.
Saludos

Fallo mio, perdona, no me di cuenta que al final de cada iteración hacias un array_push, leí el código en diagonal (esa función no la uso nunca, prefiero hacerlo con $array[]=).

@masterguru.
¿Y dónde debo poner $array[]=?, no te entiendo, disculpa.
Gracias.

jeje, perdona de nuevo, es lo mismo, es cosa de sintaxis, queria decir que esto: array_push($return_arr,$row_array); es lo mismo que escribir esto: $return_arr[] = $row_array;.  Es decir, hacen lo mismo, incorporan un nuevo elemento a la pila del array, por eso no lo ví cuando lo leí en la primera revisión de tu código, porque nunca uso la sintaxis del array_push, y pensé que sobreescribias valores.

Por otra parte, no tengo la solución a tu problema, tendria que hacer demasiadas cosas para reproducirlo y me da pereza, je.  Lo que no entiendo es que hagas un json_encode de un array y lo interpretes con $("#datos").html(respuesta); sin tratarlo antes, pero no me hagas mucho caso hoy, estoy espeso :-)

@masterguru, gracias por tu tiempo y respuestas.
Saludos.
